# How to display all errors during HTML validation at once?

Tags: html, validation

When we validate a form using HTML Validation, it displays only one error, though there could be more errors on the form. So, the user will fix only one error and will submit the form again to know that there is another error. This could be frustrating for the user and a very bad user experience. How can we see all the validation errors at once?

There is some JavaScript written by [TJ VanToll](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/05/html5-form-validation-showing-all-error-messages/), which gets all the validation errors of the form and displays at the top of the form. But I want to display all errors next to the form, in its default HTML way.